# Xcode Trigger a LocalNotification when a value is reached

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

Good Day

I have a question regarding local notifications
I am looking at a few examples online but they are all similar in a way as below where it is shown how to trigger a notification from a static time. A time that is coded manually.
For example:

```
func scheduleNotification() {
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Late wake up call"
content.body = "The early bird catches the worm, but the second 
mouse gets the cheese."
content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 10
dateComponents.minute = 30
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, 
repeats: false)
```

What I would like to see is how I am able to trigger a local notification from value similar to a reminder.

As shown in this sketch below I have a UIlabel and what value is in that UIlabel is calculated by an pod from cocoapods.
All that the value is displaying when you run the simulator is a time. But each day this time will change {mon-1:05pm tue-11:00am wed-14:17pm etc)
How is it possible to make the output which a UIlabel is displaying to trigger a notification?

[image: what the app in sim looks like]

Comment: You need to explain your situation more, what value is in the label? how does it change? if your label contains a time... just schedule the notification for that time. if the user changes the time afterwards just cancel the previous notification and create a new one

Comment: i have made edits to my question hope it helps